# Proof check: Is this a valid step using limits of a sequence random variables?

Tags: probability, limits, proof-verification, stochastic-processes

Let $B(t)$ be a Brownian motion on $[0,T]$. Let $V(B)$ be the total variation of this Brownian motion:

$$V(B) = \lim_{\Delta \to 0} \sum_{i=1}^{n} |B(i\Delta) - B((i-1)\Delta)|$$

where $n = T/\Delta$.

I want to prove the following statement:

With probability $1$,

$$\lim_{\Delta \to 0} \Delta^{\frac{1}{2}} \sum_{i=1}^{n} |B(i\Delta) - B((i-1)\Delta)| = c$$

where $c$ is some positive finite constant.

---

My attempt:

Let

$$V_n (B) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} |B(i\Delta) - B((i-1)\Delta)|$$

Now, since the increments $B(i\Delta) - B((i-1)\Delta)$ are I.I.D normal, it follows that

$$E[V_n(B)] = \sqrt n c_1$$ and $$Var(V_n(B)) = c_2$$

which means

$$E[\Delta^{\frac{1}{2}}V_n(B)] = c_3$$ and $$Var(\Delta^{\frac{1}{2}}V_n(B)) = \Delta c_4$$

for some positive constants $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4$. Hence it follows (I think?) that for any $\epsilon > 0$, we have

$$P\left(\bigg|\lim_{\Delta \to 0} \Delta^{\frac{1}{2}} \sum_{i=1}^{n} |B(i\Delta) - B((i-1)\Delta)| - c\bigg| > \epsilon \right)    (1)$$

$$= \lim_{\Delta \to 0} P\left(\bigg|\Delta^{\frac{1}{2}} \sum_{i=1}^{n} |B(i\Delta) - B((i-1)\Delta)| - c\bigg| > \epsilon \right)    (2)$$

$$= \lim_{\Delta \to 0} P\left(\bigg|\Delta^{\frac{1}{2}} V_n(B) - c\bigg| > \epsilon \right) (3)$$

$$\leq \lim_{\Delta \to 0} \frac{\Delta c_4}{\epsilon^2}    (4)$$

$$= 0    (5)$$

where we use Chebyshev's inequality, proving the result

---

The part I'm unsure of is going from (1) to (2). Is it valid to interchange limits and probabilities like this?

---

Edit: So I showed it converges in probability. Now, I'm not sure if it converges almost surely. I tried applying Borel-Cantelli theorem with no luck. Any tips?

---

Edit2: Having thought about this more, I'm now of the opinion that it does not converge almost surely, but only in probability. My thinking being that to converge almost surely, it must be different than $c$ only a finite number of times, but every time we increase $n$ we split $B(i\Delta) - B((i-1)\Delta)$ into two new normal random variables, scaled up. This seems to contradict that it is different than $c$ a finite number of times.

Comment: No, this is not possible. $\forall \varepsilon >0 \ P(|\lim_{\Delta\to 0}a(\Delta)- c|>\varepsilon)=0$ is equivalent to the almost sure convergence $a(\Delta)\to c$, while $\forall \varepsilon >0 \ \lim_{\Delta\to 0} P(|a(\Delta)- c|>\varepsilon)=0$, to the convergence in probability.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Do you have any suggestions about how to go about proving this properly?

Comment: I tried using Borel-Cantelli theorem but couldn't show it. I'm unsure if it actually converges almost surely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I suspect that there is a sequence of $\Delta_k$s that actually allow this to converge almost surely. That is because if $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability, then there is a subsequence that converges almost surely. Without knowing how you are going to zero with the deltas, I cannot say much. (I suspect since you defined it as $n = T/\Delta$, you are letting $n$ go to infinity in the "usual" sense, and thus concluding delta is going to 0, in which case, I would assume that this is in probability.)

Also, it can only be different from the limit finitely many times in almost sure convergence is actually wrong. The deterministic sequence $X_n = 1/n$ converges almost surely to 0 (for every event, it converges). What has to happen is that for any epsilon, it can only be away from that epsilon ball around the limit finitely many times (which follows from Borel-Cantelli).

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying what "almost sure convergence" means in this sense. It really helps a lot. I will approve the bounty once it lets me (there's a minimum time limit for some reason).

Comment: All good; besides, you might get a better answer in the time being... One of my friends suggested to use Gaussian tail bounds instead of Chebychev's inequality for instance and said Borel-Cantelli might work for that. Also "they will be equal in finite time" logic does indeed work for discrete cases (Since for instance, if $X_n$ is discrete, $-1/2 < X_n < 1/2$ would mean $X_n = 0$)

Answer (score 0):

For 1) implies 2) you can use Fatou's Lemma: $\{(limsup |f_n|)>\epsilon\}$ is a subset of  $liminf \{|f_n|>\epsilon\}$ and Fatou's Lemma followed by your calculation  now shows $P\{limsup |f_n|>\epsilon\}=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm still not sure how that means (1) implies (2).  If the first is a subset of the latter, would that give an $\leq$ between (1) and (2)? And hence proving the result? And if so, what conditions are necessary here to use this?

Comment: "... is a subset of ..." - no, the inclusion is rather opposite.

Comment: 1) does not imply 2), but 1) $\leq$ holds and that is what you need. Zhoraster, the inclusion I have stated is correct. If a point is not in $liminf \{|f_n|>\epsilon\}$ then $|f_n|\leq \epsilon$ for all n sufficiently large and this implies $limsup |f_n| \leq  \epsilon$

Comment: Yeah zhoraster is right (this is my third comment, though the first one I wrote was right ^.^) If fn is indicator on the parity of n, then limsup is always 1, and lim inf is always 0. As such, all the events are in the first set you defined but none are in the second set. As for your logic, you showed that if an element is not in A, then it is not in B. Therefore B is in A; not the other way around.

Comment: I have caused confusion by using bad notations. My proof is valid and here is what I wanted to write; let $g=limsup|f_n|$. Let $E_n=\{|f_n|>\epsilon\}$ and E be the liminf of the sequence of sets $\{E_n\}$. The inclusion I used was $\{g>\epsilon\}$ is contained in E. Liminf of a sequence of sets is the set of points that belong to infinitely many of the sets.